# Resolving Forces

Tags: classical-mechanics

A ball of weight $1\,\text{N}$ is placed on a slope $25°$ to the horizontal. Find the normal force experienced by the ball. I know this seems like a really simple question but I would normally take $R$ as $W\cos(25^{\circ})$ as it is perpendicular to the slope but the answer key states that $R\cos(25^{\circ}) = W$. Is there something that I am missing? The question is part of the bigger problem but to solve for $R;$ the answer key only states this : $R\cos(25^{\circ})= 0.1 g$

[image]

Original Problem : A hollow container consists of a smooth circular cylinder of radius 0.5 m, and a smooth hollow cone of semi-vertical angle 65◦and radius 0.5 m. The container is fixed with its axis vertical and with the cone below the cylinder. A steel ball of weight 1 N moves with constant speed 2.5 m s−1in a horizontal circle inside the container. The ball is in contact with both the cylinder and the cone (see Fig. 1). Fig. 2shows the forces acting on the ball, i.e. its weight and the forces of magnitudes RN and SN exerted by the container at the points of contact. Given that the radius of the ball is negligible compared with the radius of the cylinder, find R and S

Comment: What is $S?$ It looks like another force on the ball...

Comment: It looks to me like you're correct, and the book is wrong. Assuming the ball is not jumping up perpendicular to the surface, then $R=W\cos(25^{\circ})$. Then you would have a force $W\sin(25^{\circ})$ down the slope.

Comment: Unknown force. We find it out using R. The ball is moving at a constant speed on this track

Comment: Can you please state the original problem statement, word-for-word? And please define all variables.

Comment: probably the normal versus the wall.

Comment: It was a question in the Cambridge A levels and the answer was R = 1/cos(25)

Comment: The additional context is absolutely crucial, which is why I asked for the original problem statement!

Comment: Could you care you to explain please? I still don't understand why R is 1/cos(25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we are looking at the picture in the problem, we see that the ball is on the left side of the hollow container. Define $x$ positive to the right, and $y$ positive up. The forces on the ball are as follows:
\begin{align*}
mg &\quad \text{in } -y\;\text{direction: weight}\\
\frac{mv^2}{r} &\quad \text{in } -x\;\text{direction: centripetal force}\\
S_N&\quad \text{in } +x\;\text{direction: normal exerted by cylinder}\\
R_N\sin(25^{\circ})&\quad \text{in } +x\;\text{direction: } x \; \text{component of } R_N\\
R_N\cos(25^{\circ})&\quad \text{in } +y\;\text{direction: } y \; \text{component of } R_N.
\end{align*}
Now, viewed from the $xy$ axis, the system is in equilibrium. So we sum the forces and solve:
\begin{align*}
S_N+R_N\sin(25^{\circ})-\frac{mv^2}{r}&=0\quad x \text{ direction}\\
R_N\cos(25^{\circ})-mg&=0\quad y \text{ direction.}
\end{align*}
Then immediately we see that
\begin{align*}
R_N&=\frac{mg}{\cos(25^{\circ})}\\
S_N+\frac{mg}{\cos(25^{\circ})}\,\sin(25^{\circ})-\frac{mv^2}{r}&=0\\
S_N+mg\tan(25^{\circ})-\frac{mv^2}{r}&=0\\
S_N&=\frac{mv^2}{r}-mg\tan(25^{\circ}).
\end{align*}
So you were missing two things:

1. Because a preponderance of forces are horizontal or vertical, it makes more sense to resolve forces into that coordinate system, rather than a tilted coordinate system.
2. You missed the centripetal force entirely.

Comment: How does the the centripetal force which is acting only in the x-direction affect the forces in the y-direction? Supposing there was no centripetal force, would R still be same?

Comment: It only affects the component of $R_N$ in the $x$ direction. If there were no centripetal force, the $x$ component of $R_N$ would be smaller.

Comment: I think I finally got it. Thank you very much. I have my exams today and this explanation was a lifesaver.

Comment: As an aside, problem-solving strategy is quite important. You might find these pdf's I created helpful: http://mathhelpboards.com/showthread.php?28-Problem-Solving-Strategy.